# Why was the name quadratic chosen for second degree

Tags: terminology, quadratics, quartics

Quadratic is defined to be, "involving the second and no higher power of an unknown quantity or variable."

The word Quadratic always throws me off, since the number 4 immediately comes to mind, because of the Quad. Why was the name Quadratic chosen? Why couldn't something like 'Bi-atic equation be chosen'

Supposedly, an equation with the highest degree of 4 is called, quartic, which is again not very intuitive.

Comment: What's the area of a square whose side length is $x$?

Comment: http://www.latin-dictionary.org/quadratus

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151217/why-does-quadratic-describe-second-power-when-quad-means-four

Comment: Yet another place where our conventions fall victim to tradition, like electrons being negative.

Answer (score 2):

When you compute the area of a *square*, you raise the edge at the power $2$. This is where the term "squaring a number" came from. Since *"quad"*, as you correctly say, is the Latin root for *"four"*, and a square has *four* edges, a *squared* algebraic expression became a synonym of for a *quadratic* algebraic expression.